# Python 3: How can I display what cards the dealer and players have in my game of black jack?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get an output of? I have the bottom two lines.
Dealer: 9 of Diamonds; 4 of Hearts;
Alice: 2 of Diamonds; Jack of Diamonds;
Bob: 7 of Clubs; 9 of Spades;
Alice lost. Alice now has $95
Bob won! Bob now has $55

I don't know how Im supposed to call my str methods to display what cards the dealer has and what cards the two players have. I need it in that exact format but I'm not sure how to call it from main. Please let me know what could work!

```
import random

class Card():

    # initialize the card class
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.__value = value

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__value == 11:
            return "Jack of " + self.suit
        if self.__value == 12:
            return "Queen of " + self.suit
        if self.__value == 13:
            return "King of " + self.suit
        if self.__value == 14:
            return "Ace of " + self.suit
        else:
            return str(self.__value) + " of " + self.suit

    def get_value(self):
        if(self.__value <= 10):
            return self.__value
        elif self.__value <= 13:
            return 10
        else:
            return 14

class DeckOfCards():

    # initialize the deck of cards class
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
        for i in range(len(suits)):
            for j in range(2, 15):
                self.deck.append(Card(suits[i],j))

    def print_deck(self):
        for i in range(len(self.deck)):
            print(self.deck[i])

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.deck.pop()

class Dealer():

    def __init__(self, name = "Dealer"):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

    def __str__(self):
        string = self.name + ": "
        for i in range(len(self.hand) - 1):
            string += self.hand[i] + ": "
        string += self.hand[len(self.hand) - 1]
        return string

class Player():

    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.hand = []

    def __str__(self):
        string = self.name + ": "
        for i in range(len(self.hand) - 1):
            string += self.hand[i] + ": "
        string += self.hand[len(self.hand) - 1]
        return string

def main():

    deck = DeckOfCards()
    dealer = Dealer()
    players = []
    players.append(Player("Alice", 100))
    players.append(Player("Bob", 50))

    deck.shuffle()

    dealer.hand.append(deck.draw_card())
    dealer.hand.append(deck.draw_card())

    for i in range(len(players)):
        players[i].hand.append(deck.draw_card())
        players[i].hand.append(deck.draw_card())

    dealerHand=0
    for i in range(len(dealer.hand)):
        dealerHand += dealer.hand[i].get_value()
        

    for i in range(len(players)):
        playerHand = 0
        for j in range(len(players[i].hand)):
            playerHand =+ players[i].hand[i].get_value()

        if dealerHand > playerHand:
            players[i].amount -= 5
            print(players[i].name + " lost. " + players[i].name + \
                  " has now $" + str(players[i].amount))
        else:
            players[i].amount += 5
            print(players[i].name + " won! " + players[i].name + \
                  " has now $" + str(players[i].amount))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. The first is that you're not trying to print out the hands at all in the `main` function. You just go immediately on to finding what score each hand is worth and announcing who won. Fixing that is pretty easy, you just need to `print(dealer)` and add another loop over the players printing each one in turn. You're generally going the long-way around by using `for i in range(len(players))`, you can just iterate directly on the list of players instead:

```
# add this either just above or just below the `dealerHand` loop.
print(dealer)
for p in players:
    print(p)
```

The second issue you have is that your code creating the output in `Player.__str__` and the identical `Dealer.__str__` method doesn't actually convert the `Card` objects it's trying to format into strings. You need to add a `str` call anywhere you're looking up `self.hand[whatever]`:

```
def __str__(self):
    string = self.name + ": "
    for i in range(len(self.hand) - 1):
        string += str(self.hand[i]) + ": "
    string += str(self.hand[len(self.hand) - 1])
    return string
```

A few other notes, unrelated to your errors:

As I mentioned, you don't always need to loop over a range. A lot of the time, you don't need the index at all, so just loop over the values in a list, instead of indexing. For the loop in the `__str__` methods, you *arguably* do need the index since you want to treat the last value differently (not appending a semicolon), but there's a much better solution using `str.join`. Just call `"; ".join(str(c) for c in self.hand)`.

Another suggestion is to use string formatting methods, like `str.format` or the newer f-strings (which do more or less the same thing with dedicated syntax) instead of concatenating lots of strings together with `+`. The latter is much less efficient, and often prone to error, as you had in your code.

And finally, it's a bad idea to have two nearly identical classes, as you currently have with `Player` and `Dealer` (which differ exclusively in the default argument that `Dealer` provides for `name`, as far as I can tell). Either you should only have one class, or you should have two classes where one inherits most of its behavior from the other class (or possibly where two child classes inherit common behavior from a third base class).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(players)):
   for card in players[i].hand:
      print(card)
```